# Index (zero based) must be greater than or equal to zero and less than the size of the argument list. error when adding domain service class

Tags: silverlight, entity-framework, ria

I'am using a silverlight business project template to create a simple silverlight app for our company. In a different assembly i have created a data model using EF 4.2 with a code first approach. When i try to add a new domain service class i get an error message box with "Index (zero based) must be greater than or equal to zero and less than the size of the argument list.".

I'am using RIA Services V1.0 SP2 and RIA Services Toolkit (September 2011).

Anyone seen anything like this?
Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From experience: this sounds like you didn't copy the connection string of the EDMX model to the database to the correct .config file. This happens when the EDMX is in a different assembly/project.

Comment: That was the problem exactly. Thanks. Could have used a better error message though